# AppleScript to delete all user home folders except specific ones?

Tags: applescript, conditional-statements, directory, home-directory

I manage a local schools IT infrastructure. Recently thought of a situation that we may run into since we have incorporated Apple computers into the system. It deals with network users home folder stored locally on the mac. Each year we have 500+ new students, so I can only assume at some point new user names are going to be the same as somebody from a previous year. Which is fine. Except I do not want the previous users files/data loaded up when the log into the mac with their network account.

What I would like some help with is a script, possibly a unix script for ARD, that I can use to delete all users home folders (or any other information I should remove) except a list of specified ones. 
Real examples of users:
dadmin
dbaker
jdunn

Again, I do not know if this is the best way to do such a thing, but that's why I'm asking.

Also we do not use Mobile accounts. Network users log in, local profiles/home folders are created. I'm going to guess it will need to erase keychain data, as well as any other user specific information.

Comment: When answering your own question it is best to post the answer as answer and not in the question itself. That way you can tag your answer as answered.

Comment: I've posted your solution as a proper answer. Self answering of questions is allowed and even encouraged. Feel free to do so and let me know if you did, I'll remove my posted answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The OP found the solution:

> --------------------------- SCRIPT INFORMATION ---------------------------
>
> PURPOSE OF SCRIPT: Remove specific user accounts home folders on macs,
>   that are NOT mobile accounts, and only the ones that do not match
>   names given to not delete.
>
> PLATFORM: Apple iMac
>
> OS VERSION: 10.6.8
>
> TESTED and WORKS: True

```
    #!/bin/sh

echo "Deleting home directory for the following users…"

userList=`find /Users -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name "*.*" -not -name "username" -not -name "Shared" -not -name "Guest" -mtime +7 | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'`

for a in $userList ; do

rm -r /Users/"$a"; #delete the home directory

done
```

This will find users in the User directory disregarding hidden files. This will disregard the "Shared" account folder. This will disregard the "Guest" account folder. And it will disregard anyname that you change the "username" area into. To add more user names to not delete simply add more

```
-not -name "usernamegoeshere"
```

switches to the command anywhere after first -not -name "*.*" switch.

I'm sure there is a way to have it read from a file list of user names, but as I am a beginner I won't go any farther. And I got this to work by running it through the terminal. I am yet to test on ARD.

I also did a test first to make sure that it pulled the correct names, and only the ones I wanted to delete by using this script FIRST which does nothing but display the names to delete based on the given criteria defined by `-not -name "username"` switches in the script.

#!/bin/sh

```
echo "Deleting home directory for the following users…"

userList=`find /Users -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name "*.*" -not -name "username" -not -name "Shared" -not -name "Guest" -mtime +7 | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'`

for a in $userList ; do

echo "$a"

done
```